# Spark SQL : subtract respective rows of one dataframe from another

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes that have the same schema

```
df1
    col1   col2
    23     89
df2
    col1   col2
    57     72
```

i want to subtract df1 from df2 rowwise. so i want to see

```
result
col1   col2
34     -3
```

how can i achieve this in spark sql ?

Comment: with positional dependency?

Comment: what if three rows? you need to expand example

Comment: `col1   col2
34     -3` should be `col1   col2
34     -17` -> updated the answer with this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version does this for a *varying* number of columns in a DF. Just need to update `val n` to number of cols in DF.

It answers the subsequent query from the questioner which was not part of the original question.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType}
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val suffix = "_2"

def renameCols(t: DataFrame, suffix: String = ""): DataFrame = {
  t.select( t.columns.map { c => t.col(c).as( c + suffix) } : _* )
}

// Initial data
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq( (11.0, 22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 55.0), (22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 55.0, 66.0))).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5")
val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq( (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0))).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5")
val newSchema = StructType(df1.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("rowId", LongType, false)))

val rddWithId1 = df1.rdd.zipWithIndex
val rddWithId2 = df2.rdd.zipWithIndex
val X = spark.createDataFrame(rddWithId1.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema) 
val Y = spark.createDataFrame(rddWithId2.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema) 
val dfA = renameCols(X, "_1")
val dfB = renameCols(Y, "_1_2")

val df = dfA.join(dfB, dfA("rowId_1") === dfB("rowId_1_2")) 
//df.show(false)

val res = df.select(df.columns.filter(_.endsWith("_1")).map(c => col(c) - col(c+s"${suffix}")): _*).drop("(rowId_1 - rowId_1_2)")

// Number of cols generated, could alo be automated
val n = 5
val newColumns = Seq.range(1,n+1).map(c => ("c_" + c))
res.toDF(newColumns:_*).show(false)
```

returns:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|c_1 |c_2 |c_3 |c_4 |c_5 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
|10.0|20.0|30.0|40.0|50.0|
|20.0|30.0|40.0|50.0|60.0|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

the below code might be helpful,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = Seq((23,89)).toDF("col1","col2")

val df2 = Seq((57,72)).toDF("col1","col2")

val windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy(lit("A")).orderBy(lit("A"))

val df3=df1.withColumn("id",row_number.over(windowSpec))
val df4=df2.withColumn("id",row_number.over(windowSpec))

df3.createOrReplaceTempView("df3")
df4.createOrReplaceTempView("df4")

spark.sql("SELECT a.col1-b.col1 as col1,a.col2-b.col2 as col2 FROM df4 a INNER JOIN df3 b ON a.id=b.id").show()

/*
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|  34| -17|
+----+----+
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative harder way but may be better performance wise and strictly speaking correct. Shows some issues with common names with DF API.

zipWithIndex approach that preserves ordering.

Main point still, what if hundreds of cols?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType}

def renameCols(t: DataFrame, suffix: String = ""): DataFrame = {
  t.select( t.columns.map { c => t.col(c).as( c + suffix) } : _* )
}

// Initial data
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq( (1.0, 2.0), (4.0, 2.0))).toDF("c1", "c2")
val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq( (1.0, 3.0), (1.0, 2.0))).toDF("c1", "c2")

val newSchema = StructType(df1.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("rowId", LongType, false)))

val rddWithId1 = df1.rdd.zipWithIndex
val rddWithId2 = df2.rdd.zipWithIndex
val X = spark.createDataFrame(rddWithId1.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema) 
val Y = spark.createDataFrame(rddWithId2.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema) 
val dfA = renameCols(X, "_1")
val dfB = renameCols(Y, "_2")

val df = dfA.join(dfB, dfA("rowId_1") === dfB("rowId_2")) 
df.show(false)
df.selectExpr("c1_1 - c1_2 as c1", "c2_1 - c2_2 as c2").show(false)
```

Addendum

For many columns, a start, not part of answer:

```
 df.select(df.columns.filter(_.endsWith("_1")).map(c => col(c) + 1): _*).show
```

apply appropriate function to _1 and _2 cols with lit & substitution, and dropping of rowId. Good example to mull on.

Comment: thanks @thebluephantom. the number of columns is limited. it will be at most 10 in my case. now what if i dont know the column names before hand ?

Comment: u have some thinking to do

Comment: df.columns gives you columns

Comment: Added a deluxe answer.